# Disable postback OnItemClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radrotator

I have a radRotator whit an OnItemClick method which is fired when the user click on one of the items while rotating.
In the OnClick method, I get the index of the item clicked and then I make use of it.
The problem is that every time that a click is performed in the radrotator, it stops and restart all over again. I suppose this is because of the post back generated by the OnItemClick.

How can I disable the post back on the OnItemClick but still fire the command?

```
<telerik:RadRotator ID="RadRotator1" RotatorType="AutomaticAdvance" ScrollDirection="Up"
                    ScrollDuration="4000" runat="server" Width="714"
                    ItemWidth="695" Height="260px" ItemHeight="70" FrameDuration="1" InitialItemIndex="-1"
                    CssClass="rotator" OnItemClick="RadRotator1_ItemClick">
```

Comment: @stigok I have added the reason why I would like to avoid the post back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnItemClick will do a postback. I think you will have to call server side function from javascript. Since you are using telerik controls, you can use either RadAjaxManager or RadAjaxPanel to do the server side call.

$find("<%= RadAjaxPanel1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest();

The above line will make a call to RadAjaxPanel1 ajaxrequest event.

Updated code -

```
    <telerik:RadRotator ID="RadRotator1" RotatorType="AutomaticAdvance" ScrollDirection="Up"
                        ScrollDuration="4000" runat="server" Width="714"
                        ItemWidth="695" Height="260px" ItemHeight="70" FrameDuration="1" InitialItemIndex="-1"
                        CssClass="rotator" OnClientItemClicked="itemclicked">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function itemclicked(sender, args) {
       // you will have to make a server side call from here 
      // if you have RadAjaxPanel or RadAjaxManager on this page you can call ajaxRequest to   //make server side call. 
$find("<%= RadAjaxPanel1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest();


    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am not really familiar with this. Please elaborate a bit how should I proceed.

Comment: Updated my answer. you will need to call javascript function using OnClientItemClicked and make a ajax call from javascript.